# bundle not returning all css files

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have never used the BundleCollection before in an MVC project before today but I am trying to add in the jquery ui css files.

I have this defined in my BundleConfig.cs class

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

In the layout.cshtml file I have

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

But the only 2 that are rendered are

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However the jquery UI exist.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should update your question title and tags to reflect the bundler you're using.

Comment: I bet you don't have the right permissions / ownership on those files, they should be readable by the webserver.

Comment: Are the paths to the other files correct?

Comment: @RápliAndrás this is on localhost atm

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, all paths are correct but only the first 2 get included